# Remove two records with one link in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So I'm trying to delete two objects with 1 link in rails.

I'd love to do something like this:

```
<%= link_to "Remove Items", [Item1, Item2], :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
```

But it obviously doesn't do the trick.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Pass the id's of the items into the delete method then modify your delete method to iterate over the id's if you have more than one.

If you need help let me know.

Comment: The items I'm using are different classes, so I dont think passing them like that will work?

Comment: No it wont, I don't know how you would restfully delete those items. Are you working with any associations on the two objects?

Comment: nope :\ I think I might make a custom method in the controller and send in a couple params specifying what to delete.

Comment: Yeah after thinking about it I think that creating a custom delete controller would be the best route. Perhaps pass the model name and id in an array and loop over it?

Answer (score 2):

This is an expansion of Devin M's answer.

To do this, you don't have to use JavaScript. You could simply pass the ids of the objects you want to delete to a routing helper like this:

```
<%= link_to "Delete these", destroy_many_items_path(:ids => [1,2,3]), :method => :delete ... %>
```

Then you would have to define this route in your `config/routes.rb` file:

```
resources :items do
  collection do
    delete :destroy_many
  end
end
```

And then in your controller:

```
def destroy_many
  items = Item.find(params[:ids])
  items.each { |item| item.destroy }
  ...
end
```

Or as mischa points out in the comments:

```
def destroy_many
  Item.where(:id => params[:ids]).delete_all
  ...
end
```

Comment: Why would you iterate over them? How about `Item.where(:id => params[:ids]).delete_all`?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a link to an ajax controller action that will delete those two items. Writing javascript isn't so bad.